# Updating EntityFramework project to new environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm not sure exactly how to word this question.  Whenever I am publishing an entity framework application from Dev to Test and then to production I've always just changed the connection strings located in the app.config or web.config and then updated my .edmx from those dbs (update from database option).  Then did my publish or build and move the files over (from my dev machine).

However, I'm not sure that this is necessary or the correct way of doing it.  Is there a better/correct way of doing this?

And if it is a term that I can just lookup, let me know that.  I can do the research I'm just not sure how to word it.

In the project(asp.net MVC) it is using Entity Framework 6.

Comment: build configurations & continuous integration

Comment: @CristiPufu - Can you tell me if I updated the App.Config where the .edmx is located will that automatically use the new DB?  Or are there other steps I need to do to get it to see the new DB (Test/Prod)?

Comment: you have to update the web project's `web.config` for publishing. And when you run updates locally, `visual studio`uses the project's config that is set as `Startup Project`

Comment: You have to publish a version to test/production and update the belonging database to match the edmx in that version, not the other way around. How can an upgraded application even run when you update (= downgrade) the edmx?